# Need help in joining tables to get the accurate results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables, the 1st table 'LD0P0K' is the main table i need to join with 2nd 'LD0P0K01' and 3rd 'LD0P0K04' with the 1st column value 'HUSHLNR' and get the 'PNR' from both tables and then join with last table 'LD0P0A' to get the values with 'PNR'.

I tried the below solution but its not giving the data from 3rd table and giving 6 records with 2 rows for each 2nd table.

```
Select HS.HUSHLNR, HS.FOMDAT,HS.TOMDAT,HSM.PNR,HSM.FAMHUVUD,HSM.MARK,HSM.AVFOMDAT,HSM.AVTOMDAT,P.KUNDNUMMER,P.FODDAT from LD0P0K HS
LEFT OUTER JOIN LD0P0K01 HSM on HS.HUSHLNR = HSM.HUSHLNR
LEFT OUTER JOIN LD0P0K04 CHM on HS.HUSHLNR = CHM.HUSHLNR
LEFT OUTER JOIN LD0P0A P on p.PNR= HSM.PNR AND p.PNR = CHM.PNR
Where HS.HUSHLNR='906'
```

Comment: Consumable sample data (not an image), expected results, and an explanation of the logic required will help us help you.

Comment: i need to get the values of 'PNR' from table LD0P0K01 and LD0P0K04  using 'HUSHLNR' from both tables with  LD0P0K and then get the details from LD0P0A using 'PNR'

Comment: We can't access your data though, so we have no idea where these `'PNR'`, and `'HUSHLNR'` values are.

Comment: I have attached an image its shows the data.Hope that helps!

Comment: It does not. Images are not good way to transfer data. Try reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) article and editing your question.

Comment: As I said *"**Consumable** sample data (**not** an image),"*; it *doesn't* help as we can't use images (don't expect us to transcribe your data for you). [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **Union** to combined the fields

> Here is the link for **Union** to understand
> [SQL Union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

and here is the **code** change it whatever you want

```
Select HS.HUSHLNR as HUSHLNR, HS.fromdate as FromDte,HSM.PNR as PNR from LD0P0K HS 
inner JOIN LD0P0K01 HSM on HS.HUSHLNR = HSM.HUSHLNR
union
Select CHM.HUSHLNR as HUSHLNR, '' as FromDte,CHM.PNR as PNR from LD0P0K04 CHM
order by PNR
```

**Output:**
[image]